# CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header not found using fetch on GET/POST requests

Tags: nginx, cors, fetch

I'm having issues with CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on GET or POST requests using javascript `fetch`

```
Access to fetch at 'https://192.168.1.77/api/contract/list' from origin 'https://192.168.1.77:8090' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

But I can see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present when inspecting the headers.

**Response header**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Accept,Sec-Fetch-Mode,Sec-Fetch-Site,Sec-GPC,Referer,Pragma,Connection,Host,Content-Length
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 03 Feb 2022 23:51:05 GMT
Server: nginx/1.21.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
X-Debug-Token: 65149f
X-Debug-Token-Link: https://192.168.1.77/_profiler/65149f
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.0
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

**Request header**

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 192.168.1.77
Origin: https://192.168.1.77:8090
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://192.168.1.77:8090/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-GPC: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

**Fetch request**

```
fetch(url, {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
);
```

**Nginx config**

```
    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://192.168.1.77:8090';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Accept,Sec-Fetch-Mode,Sec-Fetch-Site,Sec-GPC,Referer,Pragma,Connection,Host,Content-Length' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Vary' 'origin';
        }

        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://192.168.1.77:8090';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Accept,Sec-Fetch-Mode,Sec-Fetch-Site,Sec-GPC,Referer,Pragma,Connection,Host,Content-Length' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Vary' 'origin';
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://192.168.1.77:8090';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Accept,Sec-Fetch-Mode,Sec-Fetch-Site,Sec-GPC,Referer,Pragma,Connection,Host,Content-Length' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Vary' 'origin';

            # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        internal;
    }
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: One issue is that, according to the NGINX's configuration that you've shared, `Content-Type` is not listed in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header of the response to the preflight request.

Comment: Another minor issue is that headers such as `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` are never needed on responses to non-preflight requests, and the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header is never needed in responses to preflight requests.

Answer (score 0):

From the server side, from your API that is, add the following line to have access from outside the server:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//Here the methods needed are added
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You wrote, "I can see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header…", but in the code you pasted, I do not see it. I'm looking at the **Response headers** you pasted above.
   (For clarity: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is its own key in the headers. It's not bundled into `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` or anything else.)

   You might need to return a response from the api something like this:

   ```js
   // Request:
   fetch(url, {
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       }
     }
   );


   // Response:
   const corsHeaders = {
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, OPTIONS',
     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Content-Length', // you had a very long list here, suit yourself
     // …any other headers you need… 
   };

   return new Response("cool body…", {
       headers: corsHeaders
   });
   ```

   Aside: `fetch` has `mode: 'cors'` by default, so no need to include in your request code.
2. Did you mean to fetch from
   `https://192.168.1.77:8090/api/contract/list` instead of  `https://192.168.1.77/api/contract/list`?
   Perhaps the different/missing port number is causing the cross-origin issue?

Comment: You are right it's not there in the GET response but I definitely see it in the OPTIONS response. I just edited my answer to include my nginx config

Comment: Also I already tried to add `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'` without any luck at all